# Install4j configurable form right click in text field

Tags: install4j

In install4j, I'm using a configurable form with a text field in it to enter a license key. The user can paste text in it with the key combination ctrl+v, but there is no menu when he right clicks in it.

Is there an option to enable the right click in a text field? (for users who don't know the key combinations for example)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 6.1.3 this is not available. I've added this suggestion to our issue tracker.